# .htaccess redirect 404 error to directory if it exists

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, redirect

Is there any way to make /name.html and /name/ work interoperably in the event of a 404 error?

For example, if the following fails:
http://domain.com/name.html

Then it would attempt:
http://domain.com/name/

And only go to a 404 page if that directory didn't exist? The reverse would be interesting too, going from dir to .html, and then finally to 404 on a double fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.html$ $1/ [L]
```